# Determine if Request is Local in Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node.js. While creating a web site, I will run the web site locally (on `localhost`). When it is deployed, it will run on other servers. My question is, how do I determine if a request is from localhost or not in Node? In ASP.NET, I could use `Request.IsLocal`. I'm trying to figure out how to do that in Node.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [`server.address()`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_address) to get the server address.

And [`request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) has `connection` and `socket` objects, as both might hold remote address (in a `remoteAddress` property) depending on a type of current connection.

But if the server is behind a reverse proxy, you'll have to pull it from appropriate header, most likely `x-forwarded-for`. However I'm not sure if that holds if proxies are chained.

So, to conclude, you'd do something along the lines of:

```
function cliAddress(req) {
  return req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress || req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
}

server.isLocal = function(request) {
  return server.address() === cliAddress(req);
}
```

---

And if you use [express.js](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.ip) see Express.js Req.IP API.

Comment: I am using express. However, I do not understand the link you included. I do not see `connection` or `socket` objects on the `request`