# How to forbid unauthenticated requests from public API

Tags: api, security, public

We have a web public api service used for our website. How to limit only our website can visit our api?

Website and API use the same domain, so CORS doesn't help. API is built by NodeJS & Express.

Comment: Similar question here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136710/determine-if-request-is-local-in-node-js-app

Comment: @petryuno1 I don't think so. Our concern is how to ensure the request is only from our website js, not local or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something called as JWT- JSON web token. The modern and easiest tool today for authenticating web services. Its really really simple to use JWT with nodeJs.

Step 1: Install JWT for node.

```
npm install jwt
```

Step 2: Create a JWT token. Example

```
token = jwt.sign({
                 url:"www.abc.com", 
                 param2: value2,
                 param3: value3,
                 accesstoken: casjzhiy15t4e78y8bnvkds98u2e3098nc1bxu
        }, "HASHKEY");
```

Here, the params can be anything you wish to add to the token and HASHKEY should be a string value. Thats it. Now you can copy the generated token  pass the same token to the API call's from web.

Step 3: Verifying the token in API

```
var adminToken = req.headers.admintoken;
var decoded = jwt.verify(adminToken, 'HASHKEY');
if(decoded.PARAM1 == "VALUE1"){
  //Request is coming from an authenticated source
}
```

You can refer to official JWT documentation for more detailed information.

Comment: the token is created by node or js? If node, how can you ensure the request's domain is correct? as i know, referer header is very easy to spoof.